# How to construct JSON Object based on StoredProcedureQuery Result List - SpringBoot Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would need to display stored procedure response(multiple OUT parameters) without creating any java class for that response.

ResultList may contain multiple cursors or single cursor or single string or multiple string or it could be even combination of cursors and string. I need to parse it all and display it as JSON Object. **Do we have any mapper which does these functionalities automatically?**

Now I could get data in following format using `List<Object[]>` as return object,

FirstCursor(Returns List of Object - No column names):

```
[  
 [  
  "XYZ",  
  18653  
 ]  
]
```

However I want column names too along with value.

```
[
 {
  "uname": "XYZ",
  "phone": 18653
 }
]
```

Service code for your reference,

```
public List<Object[]> getOrder(String orderNo) 
{  
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("xx.xxx.get_order_details"); 
 query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);     query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);     query.setParameter(1, "OR-1001");   
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();  
returns results;   
}
```

Above code returns only value and not it's respective column names.

Comment: Share your code what have you done, please

Comment: What database are you using? Many of them have support to return JSON

Comment: Added. @Ros5292

Comment: Oracle Database. Without creating DTO or entities, I must return resultlist as JSON ("Key" : "Value") . Do we have any approach to implement it. @SimonMartinelli

Answer (score 1):

You can return the JSON directly from the stored procedure:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
          JSON_OBJECT('uname' VALUE uname,
                      'phone' VALUE phone)
) 
FROM items
```

Read more about creating JSON:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/generating-json-data
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A

Comment: Thanks. Without modifying Stored Procedure, is't possible to parse List<Object[]>, as we don't have access to modify those procedure's.

Any other way through which we can parse List<Object[]> to JSON Object through java code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this .. this code is working for me:

```
Object obj = this.em.createNativeQuery("select * from function_name('P1',16418,'*Alcohol')").getSingleResult();
  System.out.println("--->"+obj.toString());
```

Console output will be printed json that my stored procedure/function returns.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.funciton_name
    (P1 character varying, 
     P2 bigint, 
     P3 character varying)
RETURNS TABLE(j text)
AS $function$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
select row_to_json(audit)::text as audits
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also best solution for this try it.

```
List<Map> ret = new ArrayList();
for(Object[] result : results) {
            Map row = new HashMap<>();
            row.put("uname", result[0]);
            row.put("phone", result[1]);
            ret.add(row);
        }
        return ret;
```

Comment: 1) It must be generic. Consider I have no idea on "Key", everything must be populated dynamically. 2) I get response as List<Object[]> --> how to parse it to Map(this map can be returned as JSON Object). Do we have any pre-built converters ? or do we need to do it manually?

Comment: @Raj i don't know so deeply about that but  we need to do it manually.And there is very rare cases in which case we can not know the "key" of value

Comment: @Raj but u should try this way. I think this is work in your case

Comment: Stored procedure shared by third party & we are using it for display purpose. Today procedure may return 10 fields & tomorrow they might update it by adding few more fields. We need to iterate it and show those fields in UI. Everything is dynamic here.