# map stored procedure result in springboot with entity object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My code is working fine except for one problem. The response I am not getting as expected.
I have a stored procedure that will return a list of users. Here is code

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
   @NamedNativeQuery(
      name="userslist".
      query="call list_users",
      resultclass=Users.class)})
@Entity
public class Users implements Serializable{

// these are mapped with @Column annotation with table column name 
fistname;
lastname;
age;

// getter-setter
//toString

}
```

**Calling Method**

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("userslist");
q.execute();
List<Users> userlist = q.getResultList();
```

**Return Response**

```
return new ResponseEntiry<List<Users>>(userlist,OK_status);
```

Now in post man I getting the response like:

```
[
  [
    "David",
    "Brrokes",
    21
  ]
]
```

But I want the output like this:-

```
[
  [
   "firstname":"David",
    "lastname":"Brrokes",
    "age":21
  ]
]
```

can you please let me know what I need to change to get the output like this ?

**UPDATE**
After changing the below I am getting the output ex desired but with duplicate entries. Can anyone has any idea why it's coming duplicate ?

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("userslist",Users.class);
```

Now Response is with Duplicate values:

```
[
      [
       "Firstname":"David",
        "Lastname":"Brrokes",
        "Age":21
       "firstname":"David",
        "lastname":"Brrokes",
        "age":21
      ]
 ]
```

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631627/how-to-construct-json-object-based-on-storedprocedurequery-result-list-springb helps you?

Comment: no this didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue. Not sure the exact reason but after removing the getter-setter method from Entity class I got the expected output